# PHP Inclued for Windows?

Tags: php, windows, pecl

Is there a .dll version of the [inclued](http://t3.dotgnu.info/blog/php/messy-programmers-beware.html) extension for [PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.inclued.php)?
The manual's link for [Inclued on PECL4WIN](http://pecl4win.php.net/ext.php/php_inclued.dll) doesn't help. I don't have a compiler to build my own DLL.

NOTE: The spelling "inclued" is correct!

Edit: I don't have a compiler, but do know someone with one... that's really a last resort though.

Comment: LOL.  I was about to go in and edit that when I actually read the page that link points to.  I'm glad I didn't change anything.

Comment: Yeah, 'inclued' is the worst software project name since 'memcached'!  :-)

Comment: I'm waiting for the lolcatcache or the cattache - you know, the briefcase for the cat who has everything

Comment: It's pretty much impossible to google for since Google auto-corrects when returning search results

Comment: If you quote it then Google cooperates, but I couldn't find anything of use :/

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question. I thought you were asking about PHP components being included with Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which version of PHP are you running? I know someone that can compile you a version.

### update

Alright, got this compiled - I've tested on my 5.2.6 build and it seems to work fine.

I've been told there may be problems using it in a threaded environment (e.g. Windows) but that's only a maybe. Also:

```
[13:10] <g0pz> the inclued dumpfiles will collide, because it uses PID # + increments
[13:11] <g0pz> but command line should work ok
[13:12] <g0pz> is the threaded apache version which'll have the same PID and well, a "possible" collision
```

So good luck with it :)

#### [download](http://www.uvshock.co.uk/php_inclued.dll)

Comment: Does anyone have this DLL still? The link provided 404's, and I can't find it anywhere else on the net.

Comment: @ken See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11339305/127430) below for the (semi-?) official build.

Answer (score 5):

As best as I can tell, the Windows version doesn't exist anymore.  Maybe whoever was maintaining it before had to stop for some reason.

I wonder what it takes to compile a PECL extension under Windows.

---

**Edit**

Here's some info on compiling a different PECL extension [on Windows](http://groups.google.co.uk/group/phpsoa/web/build-the-sca-sdo-pecl-extension).  You may be able to extrapolate to the inclued extension.

---

**Edit**

[WAMP Server](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) comes with PECL & PEAR.  I can actually run the command **pecl install inclued-alpha** from the Windows command-line and it goes out and tries to grab the inclued extension from the PECL site.

Unfortunately it dies when it unpacks the .tgz file and tries to compile it

```
ERROR:  The DSP inclued.dsp does not exist.
```

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for but +1 for effort!

Comment: At this point, you best bet might emailing the guy directly.  It looks like he has some personal information on his blog.  Sorry we couldn't find a perfect solution for you.

Comment: I couldn't find any contact information for him - could you let me know where it is?  Thanks

Comment: Hmmm.  I actually couldn't find any contact info there after all.  His name is Gopal Vijayaraghavan though and this seems to be his Flickr page:  http://www.flickr.com/people/t3rmin4t0r/.

Answer (score 1):

Poke me if you have any issues with inclued.

I'm just on the verge of putting out a release, I'll do a mkstemp() in windows instead of picking the PID + count.

Hopefully also with a gensvg.php which'll render the di-graph in-browser with pear::Image::GraphViz.

Comment: Hi!
I had a couple of issues... 1) the PHP file uses getopt(), which isn't available on windows yet.  2) The manual has inclued.enabled listed as PHP_INI_* which I interpreted as PHP_INI_ALL, but it's not (took me a while to figure that out!)

Comment: Apart from that it's cool.  I don't suppose you could find a way to make __autoload() work a little better? It lists all the autoloaded files as coming from the file with the __autoload() function in it, which is perfectly understandable but not too useful

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this their DLL download site? http://pecl4win.php.net/list_dlls.php

Unless I'm off on my browsing of the site?

Comment: Yes, that's the same site I linked to in the question - it doesn't have inclued

Answer (score 0):

Is this the page you are looking for?

http://pecl4win.php.net/list_dlls.php

..edit: (man, we are fast.  I swear these two duplicate answers were posted simultaniously)

Answer (score 0):

The official [PHP for Windows](http://windows.php.net/) site says:

> **PECL For Windows**
>
> PECL extensions for Windows is being worked on. The interface on the
>   pecl website will most likely be updated to offer Windows DLL download
>   right from that website. In the meantime, some extensions can be found
>   **[here](http://downloads.php.net/pierre/)**.

That "here" link leads to http://downloads.php.net/pierre/, where you will find, among the multitude of other extensions, builds of inclued for PHP 5.2 and 5.3, VC6 and VC9, thread-safe and non-thread-safe. The one matching my version of PHP seems to be working.